# Quarto document - putting two slides onto the same slide and keeping their effects

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I have the following quarto presentation. It has some "animation" and then it is following by some bullet points. I would like to try and put it all on a single slide so the bullet points would go under the "animation". When I try it, I get the bullet points on the single slide but they don't have the `auto-animation` effect (i.e. they do not move down with each click.

```
---
title: XYZ title
subtitle: A subtitle
format:
  revealjs
---


<style>
.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid transparent; /* Transparent border initially */
  background: #e83e8c; /* Background color for Circle 3 */
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

#box3-text {
  opacity: 0; /* Initially hidden */
  animation: reveal 2s linear forwards; /* Reveal animation */
  animation-delay: 4s; /* Delayed reveal */
}

@keyframes reveal {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Remove this section to hide Circle 3 initially
  // $("#show-text-button").click(function() {
  //   $("#box3-text").html("New Text"); /* Change the text when you want */
  // });
});
</script>

## {auto-animate=true auto-animate-easing="ease-in-out"}

::: {.r-hstack}
::: {data-id="box1" auto-animate-delay="0" class="circle" style="border: 2px solid black; background: #7d222b;"}
<div class="text">
  Circle 1
</div>
:::

::: {data-id="box2" auto-animate-delay="0.1" class="circle" style="border: 2px solid black; background: #ffffff;"}
<div class="text" style="color: black;">
  Circle 2
</div>
:::

::: {data-id="box3" auto-animate-delay="0.2" id="box3" class="circle" style="border: 2px solid black; background: #7d222b;"}
<div id="box3-text" class="text">
  wow
</div>
:::
:::

## {auto-animate=true auto-animate-easing="ease-in-out"}

::: {.r-stack}
::: {data-id="box1" class="circle" style="background: #7d222b; width: 350px; height: 350px;"}
<div class="text">
  Circle 1
</div>
:::

::: {data-id="box2" class="circle" style="background: #ffffff; width: 250px; height: 250px;"}
<div class="text">
  Circle 2
</div>
:::

::: {data-id="box3" class="circle" style="background: #7d222b; width: 150px; height: 150px;"}
<div class="text">
  Circle 3
</div>
:::
:::




<!--
################################################################################
-->




## Strategy {auto-animate=true}


## Strategy {auto-animate=true}

some bullet point

## Strategy {auto-animate=true}

some bullet 2

some bullet point

## Strategy {auto-animate=true}

some bullet 3

some bullet 2

some bullet point

## Strategy {auto-animate=true}

some bullet 4

some bullet 3

some bullet 2

some bullet point
```